# Tabulator table filter that uses unix time-stamp requires constant updating resulting in table reverting to page 1

Tags: tabulator

We are using Tabulator v4.9.3 with a filter where value is a calculated unix timestamp.
To keep the filter up to date with now() time, we update the filter value every 2 seconds.
And then call setFilter().
This works fine except the table reverts back to page 1 each time.

This issue is mentioned here & it says that behavior will change.
https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/3671

*To make things more consistent i will make some improvements in the next update. all modules will maintain their current state on sort/filter and then i will add a sortPositionReset and filterPositionReset (or similar) setup option to allow control over whether this resets the table or not.*

Has it changed with later versions ?

And is there a better way (best practice) to implement the filter we are using ?
I.e. create a hidden column or something along those lines.

Any helps/tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got no response on this question.
But managed to confirm that in latest version (5.5.2) the table will NOT revert to page 1 when setFilter() is called.